# MySQL JOIN Tables with referenced Columns

Tags: mysql, join

i try to get the most(30) ordered Products from the DB.

in Table Order i have a column type its values are (1 OR -1).
1 for valid user Order, -1 for a cancellation order(in this case the order has a reference ID to the user Order)

reference_id is an id of another Order (in the same order table)| one row referenced to another row.

Order Table:

```
id   |   reference_id  | type
---------------------------------- 
1    |                 | 1
---------------------------------- 
2    |                 | 1
---------------------------------- 
3    |   1             | -1
----------------------------------
```

Products Table:

```
id   |   order_id   |   quantity
----------------------------------
a    |   1          |   4
----------------------------------
b    |   2          |   7
----------------------------------
a    |   3          |   2
----------------------------------
```

MySQL Query:

```
SELECT *, sum(product.quantity) as quantity, count(*) as score 
FROM product LEFT JOIN order ON ( product.order_id=order.id ) 
WHERE (..?..) GROUP BY product.id ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 30;
```

this will select, sum and count all Products in all Orders.

BUT:

what i am looking for is:

```
if(order.type < 0 ){
    product.quantity is in minus(-)
    (quantity of the Product in the referenced Order MINUS this.product.quantity)
}
```

how to do this in the SQL Statement?
i tried somany things but without success

**as per comments requested Example:**
result should be a LIST of ordered Products grouped by product.id
Most Ordered Products:

```
Product-id   |   quantity
-------------------------------------------
a            |   2 (in 2 Orders)
-------------------------------------------
b            |   7 (in 1 Order)
-------------------------------------------
c            |   12 (in 3 Orders)
-------------------------------------------
...etc.
```

many thanks

Comment: `CASE WHEN order.type < 0 THEN (Order.quantity - product.quantity) END`. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: table (Order) has no quantity as column

Comment: ok then, what do you want to subtract `product.quantity` from?

Comment: 7alhashmi, thank you for your answers, but read what i wrote in the question. the correct result in the example above should be 9 as quantity [ (+4) + (+7) + (-2) ), because the last product has been cancelled (its Parent Order has the type -1, means Cancellation Order)

Comment: What should the count result be as per you

Comment: sorry my bad, i want to get a list of the ordered Products not the sum of the quantity of all orderedProducts, also the reselt SHOULD BE : 7 for product B, 2(4-2) for product a

Comment: Whould you show us a good example. Like what do you want the result look like? depends on the tables above.

Comment: @Rami.Q I have updated my answer, as per http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ee6e/3/0 this is exactly what you get from that query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will count the orders and give the sum as 9

This query works here  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c3a1/6/0

```
 SELECT Sum(orders.type * products.quantity) AS quant, 
       count(products.id) as count,
       products.id 
FROM   orders 
       INNER JOIN products 
               ON orders.id = products.order_id
```

if you want the count of 2 (2 products have been ordered)

```
SELECT Sum(orders.type * products.quantity) AS quant, 
       count(distinct products.id) as count,
       products.id 
FROM   orders 
       INNER JOIN products 
               ON orders.id = products.order_id
```

Count will be 1 each here and Sum will be 7 and 2 (as per your latest edit in question)

```
SELECT products.id, Sum(orders.type * products.quantity) AS quant, 
       count(distinct orders.id) as count
FROM   orders 
       INNER JOIN products 
               ON orders.id = products.order_id 
GROUP BY products.id
```

This gives exactly what you have asked for

Comment: Welcome, glad that I could help

Comment: sum is correct, and this is the point for me. another issue if you have the time: i need a list of orders type of 1 except orders which have been referenced: from the example above: the result list should caontain only 1 Order with the id 2

Comment: So you are saying for the sum we need to include type -1 but not for the count.. am I right?

Comment: your last statement is equivalent to my Answer with count(*) and LEFT JOIN, same results. What about my another question (List of orders that not referenced) also, if(order is valid only then, if type > 1 AND no other oderes references to it)

Comment: Can you kindly rephrase, Can you edit your question or start a new question to include details of expected results

Comment: hier is the link to the new Question: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446545/mysql-join-statement-referenced-field-in-same-table

Comment: I have answered there,let me know if you want to combine these two purposes... to me it seemed not linked so made separate queries

Answer (score 1):

I thank you all for your comments and Answers. but i ended up with this statement:

```
        SELECT *,
        SUM(o.type * p.quantity ) as quantity, 
        COUNT(*) as score 
        FROM product AS p 
        LEFT JOIN order AS o 
        ON p.order_id = o.id
        GROUP BY p.id ORDER BY quantity DESC LIMIT 30;
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
 SELECT sum(case when orders.type < 0 
       THEN products.quantity * -1
       else products.quantity end) as quantity,
  products.id,      
  count(products.id) as score,     
 FROM products LEFT JOIN orders ON ( products.order_id=orders.id )
 ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 30;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4c15/10/0)