# MySQL JOIN Statement - Referenced Field in same Table

Tags: mysql, join, field

how to get a list of all orders in the table except (orders which has been referenced and type of -1)

orders Table:

```
id   |   reference_id  | type
---------------------------------- 
1    |                 | 1
---------------------------------- 
2    |                 | 1
---------------------------------- 
3    |   1             | -1
----------------------------------
```

something like:

```
list = ArrayList();

if( order.type > 0 ){
    if( order.id != other_order.reference_id )
        list.add(order)
}
```

how to do this in MySQL Statement?

also the same result of this statement but using JOIN....etc:

```
select * from orders as a
where a.type > 0 AND not exists 
(select * from orders as b where a.id = b.ref_id)
```

Thanks

Comment: what language are you using to access mysql? java? have you tried anything?

Comment: language is not important, i need just the SQL Statement (query only)

Comment: why does the order table seem to reference itself?

Comment: re: also the same result of this statement but using JOIN....etc. What other table would you like to join to? You've only told us about one table in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you those records which are referenced and those which are valid

```
SELECT * 
FROM   yourtable A 
       INNER JOIN yourtable B 
               ON A.reference_id = B.order_id 
WHERE  B.reference_type > 0;
```

Comment: skv, i edited my question(provided SELECT Statement) try it here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ee6e/20

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this:

```
select * from orders
where not exists 
(select * from orders o where o.id = o.reference_id and type = -1)
```

Comment: yes, but is it possible to rewrite this using JOIN ...etc? to avoid select 2x

Comment: There's no problem doing two selects. MySql will generate a quick plan to run the query.

Comment: the correct SELECT Statement is in the question, how to rewrite it Using JOIN?

Comment: I don't understand. This *IS* a single select statement with a WHERE clause.

Comment: see skv answer please. anyway, thank you for your answers/comments